# Data received over BluetoothSocket is corrupted

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin

I have been writing an app that is supposed to send files over Bluetooth to another device that is running the same application. I had it sending files successfully but with one big problem... when I sent a file that was too large I got an out of memory exception.

So in an effort to find a workaround I began to load and send chunks of the file. It seemed to be working the way that I wanted it too until I went ahead and opened up the received files. One of the first received photos looked like this [corrupted image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LBS5sFAjddcS-wfxCGwazZ2_wWlTY6NB/view?usp=sharing). But most of the other photos, or APK files (whatever misc. "large" files) simply don't open at all. I Believe that the problem is somewhere in the logic of my loop that is sending data chunks. Possibly I am missing something simple and just sending the same chunk of data repeatedly?

Please have a look at my code below and let me know if you can spot the mistake that I am making. This is the thread that starts the sending:

```
thread {
    val file = fileManager.select(fileName)
    val inStream = file.inputStream(
    val length = file.length()

    val b = ByteArray(1000000)

    var count = 0 //used to keep track of progress through file
    var off = 0
    var numRead = 0

    val notificationManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(activity)
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("File Transfer")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material)
            .setContentText("Sending $fileName...")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setProgress(length.toInt(), 0, false)
    notificationManager.notify(BTS_Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())

    val header = "${BTS_Constants.START_MARKER}$fileName:$length:".toByteArray()
    BluetoothService.send(header, header.size.toLong(), header.size)

    while (count < length){
            try {
                numRead = inStream.read(b, off, 1000000)
                off+=numRead // is problem here?
                count+=numRead
                if (!(numRead>=0))break
                off = 0
            }catch (ae:ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) {
                BluetoothService.log("end of file reached", ae)
            }
        if (BluetoothService.send(b, length, count)){
            Log.d(TAG, "count: $count\nlength: ${length.toInt()}")
            notificationBuilder.setProgress(length.toInt(), count, false)
            notificationManager.notify(BTS_Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
        }
    }
    notificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setContentText("Finished sending")
    notificationManager.notify(BTS_Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

In the a chunk of the file is read int memory, given a header and sent using the `BluetoothService.send()` function. If `send()` returns true, progress is updated. Here is `BluetoothService.send()`:

```
@Synchronized fun send(bytes:ByteArray, fileLength:Long, progress:Int):Boolean{
    var synThread:ConnectedThread? = null
    synchronized(this@BluetoothService){
        synThread = mConnectedThread
    }

    var success:Boolean

    try {
        synThread?.write(bytes, progress, fileLength.toInt())
        success = true
    }catch (e:Exception){
        success = false
    }

    return success
}
```

The send function calls synThread's `write()` function. `synThread` is a `ConnectedThread`? object. Here is the definition for `ConnectedThread` containing the write function definition:

```
class ConnectedThread(val socket: BluetoothSocket) : Thread(){
    var fileName:String = ""
    var fileLength:Int = 0

    val inStream:InputStream
    val outStream:OutputStream
    val outBuffer:ByteArray
    var inBuffer:ByteArray
    var fOut:FileOutputStream? = null
    var bytes:Int = 0
    var active = true
    val notifyManager = BluetoothService.context?.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    var notifyBuilder:NotificationCompat.Builder? = null

    init {
        inStream = socket.inputStream
        outStream = socket.outputStream
        outBuffer = ByteArray(1000000)
        inBuffer = ByteArray(1024)
        notifyBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(BluetoothService.context)
        notifyBuilder?.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material)
                ?.setContentTitle("Downloading")
    }

    override fun run() {
        BluetoothService.log("$this waiting to read . . .")
        while (active){
            try {
                bytes += inStream.read(inBuffer)
                var header = String(inBuffer)
                if (header.startsWith(BTS_Constants.START_MARKER)){
                    this.fileName = header.substringAfter(BTS_Constants.START_MARKER).substringBefore(":")
                    this.fileLength = (header.substringAfter(":").substringBeforeLast(":")).toInt()
                    val path = "${Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS}/$fileName"
                    val outFile = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(path).toURI())
                    if (outFile.exists()){
                        BluetoothService.log("file already exists")
                    }else{
                        outFile.createNewFile()
                    }
                    fOut = outFile.outputStream()
                    inBuffer = ByteArray(1000000)
                    bytes = 0
                    notifyBuilder!!.setContentText("file: $fileName")
                            .setProgress(0, 0, true)
                            .setOngoing(true)
                            .setVibrate(LongArray(1){
                                10000L
                            })
                    notifyManager.notify(BTS_Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyBuilder!!.build())
                    BluetoothService.log("name = $fileName, length = $fileLength")
                }else if(bytes>=fileLength){
                    notifyBuilder!!.setProgress(0, 0, false)
                            .setContentText("Download complete")
                            .setOngoing(false)
                    notifyManager.notify(BTS_Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyBuilder!!.build())
                    //possibly save last bytes of file here
                }else{
                    BluetoothService.log("bytes: $bytes read: $inBuffer")
                    fOut?.write(inBuffer)
                }
                BluetoothService.log("read $bytes bytes: $inBuffer")
            }catch (ioe:IOException){
                BluetoothService.log("failed to read from $socket", ioe)
                cancel()
            }
        }
    }

    //WRITE FUNCTION
    fun write(bytes:ByteArray, progress: Int, length:Int){
        BluetoothService.log("writing bytes from $this")
        outStream.write(bytes)
        outStream.flush()
        BluetoothService.log("bytes written")
    }

    fun cancel(){
        BluetoothService.log("closing socket, read may fail - this is expected")
        active = false
        socket.close()
    }
}
```

So once again I believe this is a mistake being made somewhere in my loop logic, but I can not see it. Please help me to find this problem and a solution. Thank you.

Updated loop:

```
while (totalRead < length){
    try {
    numRead = inStream.read(b, 0, b.size)
    if (numRead<=0)break
    totalRead+=numRead
         }catch (ae:ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) {
    BluetoothService.log("end of file reached", ae)
             }
    if (BluetoothService.send(b, 0, numRead)){
    Log.d(TAG, "totalRead: $totalRead\nlength: ${length.toInt()}")
    notificationBuilder.setProgress(length.toInt(), totalRead, false)
    notificationManager.notify(BTS_Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
       }else{
    BluetoothService.log("Error sending data", BluetoothServiceException())
                 }
                }
```

And updated send function:

```
@Synchronized fun send(bytes: ByteArray, offset: Int, length: Int):Boolean{
    var synThread:ConnectedThread? = null
    synchronized(this@BluetoothService){
        synThread = mConnectedThread
    }

    var success:Boolean

    try {
        synThread?.write(bytes, 0, length)
        success = true
    }catch (e:Exception){
        success = false
    }

    return success
}
```

And updated write function:

```
fun write(bytes: ByteArray, offset: Int, length: Int){
    BluetoothService.log("writing bytes from $this")
    outStream.write(bytes, offset, length)
    outStream.flush()
    BluetoothService.log("bytes written")
}
```

I've noticed something interesting in the properties of received photos. The size of file before being sent, and the size of file once received. The size of photo being sent is 5.05MB and when received it show as being 526 MB.

Comment: `if (BluetoothService.send(b)`. My god.. Dont send the whole buffer. There are only numBytes in it. The buffer probably is not filled. Cant you read? Look at my loop. There is clearly `
  `int nsend = BluetoothService.send(b, 0, numRead);`.

Comment: @greenapps Ok. But look at the write function. The old version. It didn't make sense. It sent the whole buffer. It didn't use write(byte[], int, int), it used write(byte[]). So send(b) is the same as send(b, 0, numRead) because the second and third params have not been used. My mistake. I will update write function.

Comment: Your old function does the same as your new function. Both send the whole buffer. And the old version has two extra parameters which are not used for writing. So you have to write a better write() function yet.

Comment: @greenapps i posted update to my loop, send and write functions. also i posted a note at the bottom about the file size. Size of file being sent is 5.05 MB and size of same file when received is 526MB.

Comment: @greenapps i posted update to my loop, send and write functions. also i posted a note at the bottom about the file size. Size of file being sent is 5.05 MB and size of same file when received is 526MB. Still having same problem.

Comment: `The size of photo being sent is 5.05MB and when received it show as being 526 MB.` ?????? A hundred times as big? But indeed its a good idea to look at the amount of bytes you send and the amount of bytes received. You better test your function with files of less than 100Kb as then tests are much quicker done.

Comment: The write() function now looks ok. Be it that you dont use the offset parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It should me more a loop like

```
while ( totalRead < length ) 
   {
   int numRead = inStream.read(b, 0, 1000000)

   if ( numread <= 0 )
       break;

   totalRead += numRead;

   int nsend = BluetoothService.send(b, 0, numRead);

   if ( nsend != numRead ) 
       well then you should make another loop here to send all
   }
```

And if a boolean is returned it is more like

```
if (!BluetoothService.send(b, 0, numRead) )
{
 // handle error

 break;
}
```

Comment: My BluetoothService.send() funtion returns a boolean. What should it return as an Int? the number of bytes written?

Comment: Ok. Then i'm mistaken. It returns true or false. If it returns true that means that all numRead bytes are written. So then you can stay in the loop.

Comment: A buffer of `1000000` is not needed. `10000` would be enough. Hardcoded sizes is no good. Cant you replace that number by b.size() or b.length or b.length() or so ?

Comment: I will update buffer size. And yes Boolean is returned by send indicating if bytes have been sent. Would you say it's likely my problem is in the way I increase my `off` variable. The one I use for the offset in my call to `inStream.read()`? You can see it in the first section of my post. I marked it with a comment.

Comment: You should not use that off variable anymore. I showed you how to do it. Thats all you need. Look at my loop. Pleae show your new lop in an extra code block.

Comment: i updated my buffer size to be b.size, also i posted my updated loop and updated ConnectedThread.write() function. however i am still having the same problem. the only difference i see between my new loop and your example is the way that i handle my exception. if `send()` returns false it indicates an error so `if(BluetoothService.send(b)){/*update progress here*/}else{BluetoothService.log("Error sending data", BluetoothException())}` is sort of mimicking a try catch block. Also i would like to note that the topmost portion of the photos received is not jumbled.

Comment: But is you receive a hundred times more bytes? The amount should be equal. Not one byte more or less. I'm pretty confused now by all the code. Could you just post the code as you have now. And remove all old stuffplease.

Comment: And you can throw an exception. But does that happen? Dus the whole send loop end normally and totalsend == length at the end? Just always take the same small file while testing So you know its size exactly. Every byte counts.